# How to remove preserve scroll position in Adobe XD

Tags: adobe-xd

I'm beginning to use Adobe XD but my artboard links are automatically preserving the scroll position instead of going to the top. Is there a setting where I can remove this?

Here is an example of the setting of my links. I do not know how I can remove this feature.

[image]

I simply want my links to redirect to the top of the desired page instead of preserving the scroll position. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple.

i. Click on the **Prototype** on the top and select the artboard. It will reveal the link(s) made on this artboard. 
ii. Click the *starting node* of the link, and you will details in pop-up. 
iii. Uncheck the **Preserve Scroll Position** from the bottom!

[image: **Unchecking the *Preserve Scroll Position***[1]]